# Having a problem starting certain apps without stealing focus

Tags: c#, windows-10

EDIT: I believe I've found a sort of workaround by parenting Spotify to a Windows Form, and starting Spotify along with the form and parenting it at startup, and then when Spotify is restarted it's parented to the form, it is not nearly as violent. It is ok for my use, but for others it may not be enough.

I've been trying to start a program (specifically Spotify) without it stealing focus on Windows 10. The code below is as far as I've gotten, and I don't fully understand it as it isn't my code, but it seems to work on some programs, but not others. I've also tried changing focus to the window that was previously opened, but that disrupts full-screen applications, and still steals focus for a second or two.

I'm looking for some other way to open a program, that doesn't steal focus, or some sort of workaround. Mainly, I don't want to disrupt full-screen applications. I'm relatively new to C#, so keep that in mind. Not sure if this helps, but I'm running this on a WinForms application. Also not sure if this helps, but my end goal is to restart Spotify without disrupting the user/stealing focus.

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public Int32 cb;
            public string lpReserved;
            public string lpDesktop;
            public string lpTitle;
            public Int32 dwX;
            public Int32 dwY;
            public Int32 dwXSize;
            public Int32 dwYSize;
            public Int32 dwXCountChars;
            public Int32 dwYCountChars;
            public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
            public Int32 dwFlags;
            public Int16 wShowWindow;
            public Int16 cbReserved2;
            public IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public int dwProcessId;
            public int dwThreadId;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool CreateProcess(
            string lpApplicationName,
            string lpCommandLine,
            IntPtr lpProcessAttributes,
            IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
            bool bInheritHandles,
            uint dwCreationFlags,
            IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            string lpCurrentDirectory,
            [In] ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
            out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
        );

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        const int STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 1;
        const int SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4;
        const int SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7;
        const int SW_FORCEMINIMIZE = 11;

        public static void StartProcessNoActivate(string cmdLine)
        {
            STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
            si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
            si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
            si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE;

            PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

            CreateProcess(null, cmdLine, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, true,
                0, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, out pi);

            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried with `SW_SHOWMINIMIZED`?

Comment: Yea, I've tried the other ones like SW_SHOWMINIMIZED, they don't seem to change anything.

Comment: Sometimes apps don’t play nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an idea that I might be able to run programs inside the windows forms. Turns out you can. I parented Spotify to a Windows Form, and by starting Spotify along with the form and parenting it at startup, and when Spotify is restarted from the form, it's parented to the form, and that doesn't seem to steal focus. Here's my code. The button click isn't necessary, that's just there for me to open Spotify again once I've closed it. I'm not sure if this will work on other programs, but I imagine it would.

Edit: This makes the apps play nicer, and for some programs it now won't steal focus, but for fullscreen apps it does seem to mess with them. Sometimes it will minimize them, and sometimes it will not mess with it at all. It is not nearly as violent as just opening it, though. Honestly, I have no idea why.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo ps1 = new ProcessStartInfo("C:/Users/Jacob/AppData/Roaming/Spotify/Spotify.exe");
                ps1.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
                Process p1 = Process.Start(ps1);
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // Allow the process to open it's window
                appWin1 = p1.MainWindowHandle;
                // Put it into this form
                SetParent(appWin1, this.Handle);
                // Move the window to overlay it on this window
                MoveWindow(appWin1, 0, 0, this.Width / 2, this.Height, true);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error");
            }
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern long SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern long SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, long hWndInsertAfter, long x, long y, long cx, long cy, long wFlags);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);

        IntPtr appWin1;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo ps1 = new ProcessStartInfo("C:/Users/Jacob/AppData/Roaming/Spotify/Spotify.exe");
                ps1.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
                Process p1 = Process.Start(ps1);
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // Allow the process to open it's window
                appWin1 = p1.MainWindowHandle;
                // Put it into this form
                SetParent(appWin1, this.Handle);
                // Move the window to overlay it on this window
                MoveWindow(appWin1, 0, 0, this.Width / 2, this.Height, true);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error");
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.appWin1 != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                MoveWindow(appWin1, 0, 0, this.Width / 2, this.Height, true);
            }
            //base.OnResize(e);
        }
    }
```